# How to export Google Voice data with EST times (not GMT)?

Tags: google-voice, google-takeout

When using Google Takeout to export Google Voice data, it gets exported as GMT time. How can I export it with EST time?

Comment: Why EST instead of EDT (current US Eastern time)?